# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freezes on Dell G7 7588

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, external-hdd

Two challenges with my Dell G7 15 7588 and Ubuntu 18.04

1. Ubuntu freezes when the (nVidia 1060 Max Q) GPU is used.  Tried modifying the GRUB to not use it by adding nouveau and tried installing the driver from nvidia, it did not work yet.  Hence had to revert back and use Intel's default GPU.
2. Whenever I plug in an external harddisk, Ubuntu freezes a minute or two after the auto mount kicks in.

Comment: Here is not freezzing, but I can't use my second monitor after install nvidia driver, even if I revert to use Intel graphic card.

Comment: A reviewer thinks this question should be closed as off topic because of a bug. I don't think this is a bug, it's pobably a hardware issue with the Dell G7 15 7588. This is a known issue with recent models of Dell laptops..